# tfs 2013 build failed wth no error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

my situation is this. I have code in TFS2010, the code builds and works perfectly fine in VS2010 and is currently deployed in production server.
Then the admin took the code directory itself, open the code in VS2013, and check in to TFS2013 server.

When i use VS2013 to download the code and build, it will not build but showed no errors. other developers don't have any problem with this. Just me.

i deleted the suo file, project file and still nothing. I made sure to add all references back to the project and still nothing.

However, if i go into my c drive, copy the project folder from VS2010 and paste that to a different location, and then build it as a project in vs2013, it will convert the project to 2013 and then create the backup folder. now if i debug, the project will run fine. While having the project open in VS2013, I delete the backup folder that VS2013 created when it was converting the project to VS2013, it will fail. It will also fail when i close the project and reopen it.

i have spent more than 10 hours on this but still can't find the answer. please help if you ran into this problem before. thank you

Comment: If you have spent 10 hours then I would reimage your machine.

Comment: What is the message in the output window in VS after the failed build?

Comment: just build 0 failed 1 skip 0.

Comment: If you switch the drop down at the top of the ouput window arebthere any other messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstall of VS2013 did the job

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a messed up workspace. You should delete the workspace in 2013, remove all the files from that workspace on disk, then close Visual Studio. Just to be sure you can run "tf workspaces delete *" from an elevated developer prompt.

When you open it it will create a new default workspace. Map your solution, get latest, and build from there.

Comment: went to workspace in vs2013 and remove the only workspace i have. then i deleted all files from that mapping, closed vs2013, reopen and map with new directory and yet it still shows 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========.

still no errors